# How can I use recaptcha within a fancy msgBox like SWAL2 (JS/JQ)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recaptcha, sweetalert

**EDITED: Oops posted conflicting old code - fixed what I have.**

If I post the div right after body, works fine.

I put it in a html var and display it in a SWAL2 (https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2 ) box, and it doesn't show up.
This isn't necessarily a question about SWAL2 specifically, but more like how to use recaptcha after the DOM is loaded , then add recaptcha later (such as this SWAL2 box).

Here is my code:

INDEX

```
...
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
</head>
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var onloadCallback = function () {
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
             'sitekey': 'myKeyyyyyyyyyyyyyy123'
    });
});



// SWAL2 'fancy msgBox'
var html = var html = "<div id='recaptcha'></div>";
swal({
    title: 'Humanity Check',
    html: html
});
```

Answer (score 0):

INDEX //remove onloadCallback

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit" async defer></script>

<div id="generate">generate</div>
```

JS // make sure #recaptcha exist before render

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#generate').on('click', function () {

        var html = "<div id='recaptcha'></div>";
        swal({
            title: html,
            html: true // set to true to render HTML
                  ^^^^
        });
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
            'sitekey': '******'
        });
    });
});
```